# Can I give a useful generic type to a function that copies an object with a key added or replaced with a new value?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have written the following function:

```
function extend(obj, key, value) {
    return { ...obj, [key]: value }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like be able to use this function generically, with `obj` being an `Object` whose type will be known at the callsite, `key` being a string which is constant at the callsite, and `value` a value whose type is known at the callsite. `obj` might or might not already contain the `key`, and the old value associated with that key may or may not be of the same type as the new `value`.

I've looked through the [Utility Types reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), but I can't see anything that would allow me to write a useful type for `extend`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) (read the whole page to understand what is going on here):

```
function extend<T extends object, Key extends PropertyKey, Value>(obj: T, key: Key, value: Value): T & Record<Key, Value> {
    return { ...obj, [key]: value } as T & Record<Key, Value>;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB5WWAJgHgCorqZYDOicARgFbLQA0iA0sgJ6EbZkAKATnAA7IeUFsxYMAagEMANiGQA+ABSUqALkR4GAa1YaxDAG6z5G6XOQBKDQQBkiAEq04PXAcTn5CxAG8AsABQiMGIPMhQIDxIPogAdPGqDADauiwAuhrGFogAvohSZHaOzq447p6KANyBOYGBEAgkUIggJEKIALy+iDBYGgAsAEy51QH1jc0UlJ3sxEqtQgwARGBSALbIS8tTFEuWowD0ByGIAHoA-HUBDWAkcDLIsTJwAOZKO7GrG-tAA)